# Importing RxJS 6 operators into Angular 6 files by default

Tags: angular, rxjs6

My app written in Angular uses several RxJS 6 operators in almost every file, such as `filter`, `take`, and `takeUntil`. Explicitly importing these operators is a real pain. I would prefer to have them globally available.

For example, this code would no longer be needed in every file in the project.

```
import { filter, take, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Is there a way to import these operators by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NO**, there is no way to import them by default or way to share across various components/services.

You need to explicitly import wherever you want to add them since angular provides a better way to create application without dependencies.